# Writing a set as the union and/or intersection of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following problem, that I'm not sure I comprehend clearly.

> Suppose we have $S = \{(x,y) \in  \mathrm{R}_{+}^{2}: c_1x+c_2y \leq m + v, x\leq m/c_1 \} $ where $c_1 , c_2, m, v > 0$.
>    Describe this set as the union and/or intersection of two sets"

The way I understand this is the following. $S$ is a set of tuples $(x,y)$ such that each tuple in the set follows the two given predicates, i.e $c_1x+c_2y \leq m + v$ and $x\leq m/c_1$.

So, I proposed the following solution, but I am not quite sure, as it seems too simple.

Let $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathrm{R}_{+}^{2}: x\leq m/c_1  \}$ and let $B =\{(x,y) \in \mathrm{R}_{+}^{2}: c_1x+c_2y\leq m+v \} $ then $S = A \ \cap B$

Is it as simple as that ? Or did I missunderstand something?

Comment: It is correct. An even simpler answer would be $S\cup\emptyset $ or $S\cap \mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x,y)\in S$ $\iff$ $(x,y)\in\mathrm{R}_{+}^{2}$ and $  c_1x+c_2y \leq m + v, x\leq m/c_1 $

$\iff$($(x,y)\in\mathrm{R}_{+}^{2}$ and $  c_1x+c_2y \leq m + v$ and ) ($(x,y)\in\mathrm{R}_{+}^{2}$ and $ x\leq m/c_1 $)

$\iff$ $(x,y)\in A\cap B$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is that it? Is it really this simple ?

Comment: Yes, the point is the fact  $\forall x [p(x)\wedge q(x)] \equiv [\forall x (p(x))]\wedge [\forall x(q(x))] $